# If $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, show that the following equals null matrix.

Tags: matrices

> If $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, show that
>   $$ \left(  \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\
>        \omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
>         \omega^2 & 1 & \omega \\
>         \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
>         \omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
>         \omega^2 & 1 & \omega \\
>         \omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix} \right) 
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>         1  \\
>         \omega  \\
>         \omega^2  \\
>         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
>         0  \\
>         0  \\
>         0  \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to solve this and I reduced the L.H.S. to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 +2\omega+2\omega^2 \\
        2 +2\omega+2\omega^2 \\
        2 +2\omega+2\omega^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$ (since $\omega^3=1$)
but couldn't equate it to R.H.S.

Please provide your assistance.
Thank you

Comment: Hint : factor $w^3-1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy That's good enough for an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: $(w-1)(w^2+w+1)$?

Comment: @chndn Yes. Now what do you know about $\omega ^2+\omega +1$? What is $\omega$?

Comment: @GitGud okay take common 2 outside. Well what is w? I know $\omega^3=1$

Comment: @chndn I just realised what you're trying to prove is false. It's not enough $\omega$ is a complex cubic root of $1$. You need $\omega \in \Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$. Assuming this, what more can you conclude from the fact that $\omega ^3=1$?

Comment: @GitGud $w^4=w$ and so on? that is all i know

Comment: @chndn $\omega ^3=1\implies \omega ^3-1=0\implies(\omega-1)(\omega ^2+\omega +1)=0 \implies \omega -1=0 \lor \omega^2+\omega +1=0$. Can you conclude?

Comment: @GitGud So, if the first one is zero, how will it be equal to $0$? ...   +1

Comment: @chndn The first one can't be $0$. Why? The answer is somewhere in my comments.

Comment: @GitGud is it that w is complex?

Comment: @chndn If $\omega -1=0$, then $\omega =1\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @chndn Now that you've figured out the answer,I suggest you write it yourself and accept it so this question doesn't show as unanswered.

Comment: Answer has been provided. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\omega^3=1 \Rightarrow ω^3−1=0 \Rightarrow (ω−1)(ω^2+ω+1)=0 \Rightarrow ω−1=0 \lor  ω^2+ω+1= 0$$

Since, $\omega \neq 1 $ as it is complex , $ω^2+ω+1=0$

Hence, LHS = RHS

*- Answer originally posted as comment by Git Gud*

Comment: I have presented the answer for the stackexchange community as per Git Gud's comment. Hope you understood. Thank you